# Count[] with conditionals

Tags: programming

I run the following code and I got what I want

```
a = Table[
   EuclideanDistance[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[]], 
    RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[]]], 1000];
Length[Select[a, # < 0.5 &]]
```

I don't know why when I run

```
Count[a,# < 0.5 &]
```

I got 0, shouldn't Count[a,# < 0.5 &]=Length[Select[a, # < 0.5 &]]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second arg of `Count` expects a pattern, not a function. You could use either or the following:

```
In[29]:= Count[a, _?(# < 0.5 &)]

Out[29]= 763

In[30]:= Count[a, x_ /; x < 0.5]

Out[30]= 763
```

Answer (score 3):

Help says Count argument should be a *pattern*.

So do this

```
Count[a, x_ /; (x < 0.5)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`# < 0.5 &` is not a pattern. It is a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `CountsBy` function, where you can use a test directly:

```
{f, t} = Values@CountsBy[a, # < 0.5 &]
```

> `{246, 754}`